# Linux Mint: How to disable or remove applications comment from favorites menu?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop

How can I disable or remove application comments from the "favorites menu" on Mate? Or remove them completely from Mint?

[image]

There is an option for disabling comments from "all applications menu" but not for "favorites menu".

Comment: What comments? Which desktop environment? On my Cinnamon, hovering the favorites causes text to appear on the bottom right of the menu, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @terdon mint, maya, mate! short description/comment displayed under application name. http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-olfny1DtNcY/T70TQjsuDVI/AAAAAAAAI_c/95VBLIrsdZY/s1600/linux-mint-13-mate.png

Comment: Can't you edit each one and set it's comment to blank?

Answer (score 2):

The comment is taken from the corresponding `.desktop` file. These files should be either in your `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` folder or in `/usr/share/applications/`. Just edit the `.desktop` file of the program whose comment you want to remove and set it's comment field to blank. For example:

```
$ grep Comment= ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
```

So, open that file with your favorite text editor, and delete the comment so it looks like this:

```
Comment=
```

That should remove the comments from your menu (and all other places where the comment might be displayed).

Comment: Thanks, however the problem with this solution is that favorites menu still preserves comment space. In fact they are not removed from menu.

Comment: @JohnS I don't think you can do better than that. The menu is probably hard coded to print something like `$comment\n`. If `$comment`is blank, it will still print the empty line. You will probably have to modify the menu's source for this.